# ASP.NET MVC3 generic controler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, controller

I have written a bit of code today which smells somewhat.

```
public class SomeController : GenericController<SomeViewModel, SomeModel>
```

Here is a Generic Controller constrained to a particular Model and ViewModel; now what smells is the fact that I am defining the relationship between the Model and the ViewModel I don't mind that the Controller knows about the ViewModel that's fine. What I wish this to do is have the Controller ask the View Model somehow because that's where the coupling should be in my view.
The only way I can think of is in the controller factory. That could inspect the supplied ViewModel and create and instance of the Controller with the Model defined at runtime.

so the above would just become

```
public class SomeController : GenericController<SomeViewModel, TModel> where TModel : Model
```

And only be typed at runtime.
any ideas on how to do this? reflection? generics? attributes?
or is this just a really bad idea?

### ============Edit===========

the reason for the use of generics is there is a lot of shared code throughout the controllers
the controllers use services which intern use repositories.
the services and repositories depend on the type of domain object.
the methods such as `public ViewResultBase Add(TViewModel viewModel)` in the Generic Controller uses a generic mapper which converts the ViewModel to a Model and passes this to the service -> repository.

### ============Edit===========

heres a snippet from the base class showing some shared code utilising the generic arguments

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual PartialViewResult List(int id)
    {

        var model = BuildListDetails(id);

        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [Dependency]
    public IService<TDomainObject> Service { get; set; }

    protected IEnumerable<TViewModel> BuildListDetails(int id)
    {
       
        var nodes = Service.GetData(UserState.Current.User.UserID, id);
        if (nodes == null) return null;

        return nodes.Select(n => ModelMapperFactory<TDomainObject, TViewModel>.Instance.Create(n)).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

cheers,

Comment: What reason would there be to constrain the controller to a specific model and view model type? Showing an action method where these generic arguments are used would be helpful in determining the usefulness of a solution.

Comment: What smells is not the fact that you have defined a relationship between the Model and the ViewModel. A ViewModel is associated to a view. And a controller could have multiple actions working with different views. So what really smells here is the association between the controller and the ViewModel. So don't do that. Never associate a controller with a ViewModel. That's not what a ViewModel is intended  to be associated with. So I would rethink this design.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov this may be the case for lots of implementations but not this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

Darin is right (as always).  Controllers can work with different models and different views and different view models.  Typing your controller to one specific view model and model is just pointless, unless you know for a fact that you will always use just that one view model and just that one model.

There is an association between view models and models.  This association is handled in the controller.  That's one of its purposes.  Don't spend a lot of effort trying to genericize controllers, they typically only contain very specifc code related to its use, and have few options for reuse.  When you do need more options, consider using aspects or base clases that just abstract the reusable part (some people authentication logic in a base class, which I don't agree with.. but it's a choice.. other people add their own custom IPrincipal, or other kinds of common features.  In most cases, this would not require using generics).

Comment: This is exactly the case each ViewModel and Model is handled by its own controller.

Comment: @Mark - Really?  You use a seperate controller for your Create, Edit, and list views?  That seems quite odd.  Or are you using the same View model for all view types?  If so, that's the real smell.

Comment: Each Controller handles CRUD using the same viewModel. For example AnimalController may be generic supplying functions using lists, Cat and Dog Controllers can use this to get a lot of stuff for free such as a link to the IAnimalService.SaveAnimal (DogService:IAnimalService) which would magically call the concrete implementation of the service.

Comment: the views are in a separate project and determined by our own  allowing us to swap them out and fall back during runtime.

Comment: @Mark As I said, that's the real smell.  CRUD functions each have different requirements.  Using the same view model for all of them defeats the very purpose of a view model.  A view model is supposed to be tailored to your views needs, and you can't do that if you're having to make compromises to make it work across all CRUD operations.  As an example, why should you have validation attributes on list view?  Or a delete view for that matter.  Create and edit validation scenarios may be different, etc..